# Trouble deploying rails into amazon ec2 - URI::InvalidURIError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

On my amazon EC2 server, after I install ruby/rails/rbenv I run into an `URI::InvalidURIError` error. I'm not sure if I might have an issue with the way I installed `rbenv`.

```
rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.6.2 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
Exiting
home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:21:in `split': URI must be ascii only "tcp://0.0.0.0\u{feff}:3000" (URI::InvalidURIError)
from /home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:73:in `parse'
from /home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/uri/common.rb:227:in `parse'
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, you managed to add an invisible [`<U+FEFF>`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/FEFF/index.htm) character at the end of your command-line:

```
rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0[<U+FEFF> is here]
```

Remove this character from your command-line, and your server should boot fine:

```
rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0
```